# Placing a Custom Callout Over the Annotation

Tags: ios

I have the following code to create a custom callout for MapView.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    guard let annotation = view.annotation as? FloodAnnotation else {
        return
    }

    let annotationPoint = mapView.convert((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, toPointTo: mapView)

    // get the location of the point
    var point = mapView.convert((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, toPointTo: mapView)

    let fancyCalloutView = FancyCalloutView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

    fancyCalloutView.center = point

    view.addSubview(fancyCalloutView)
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

The callout appears when the click on the annotation on the right hand side. I believe this is due to the fact that the callout is a subview of the annotation view and hence using that coordinate system to position itself. How can I get the callout to appear just above the annotation view?

Comment: what happens when you not set the center point at all? comment out that line please

Comment: If I don't center than the callout view uses the 0,0 origin as I have specified and puts the top left corner of the callout on the top left corner of the annotation view.